# How do I show the upload status in the notification bar?

Tags: notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean, htc-one

I have an HTC One.  I recently went to Settings --> Apps and disabled "Show Notifications" on one of the apps listed that prevented showing the upload status of whatever I upload (Facebook video, pictures, etc.) in the notification bar.  I can't remember for the life of me which "App" this was - how do I re-enable showing uploads on my notification screen?  I am using 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most apps, if not all, have the `Show Notifications` checkbox. I suppose you'll just have to go through all your apps, and see which one was unchecked and check it again.

[image]